# how to add custom item in dropdown while using sql datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I am wondering is there any possibility of adding an item as pre-selected item in dropdown list while the dropdown list is bind to sqldatasource..?

Comment: the link you shared is only showing how to select a listitem as default that is not what I'm trying to do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following .aspx markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="DropDownList1" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDS" 
    DataTextField="city" 
    DataValueField="id"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDS" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [id],[city] FROM [cities]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can set the default drop down option to the second item in the drop down from server side like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

Or from the client (using jQuery) like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#DropDownList1').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If we use the drop down in my example - I retrieve a list of cities from the database to be displayed in the drop down.Let's say I want to add a new city that is not in the database, you can use `UNION` keyword for that and join your SQL data with a hardcoded value:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT [id],[city] FROM [cities] UNION SELECT 10,'New York'";
    }
}
```

Comment: still its same as listing ur db table and adding a custom item in script..

Comment: You asked to set a pre selected item.I suggested two solutions to do that.What is the problem?

Comment: You are clearly not understanding the question... i dont need an item from my sql source as default.. I need custom item(not in sql source)..

Comment: Exactly what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

set selected index of dropdown list through code as desired.

Comment: I know how to do this task through code I want to know if there is such way to avoid extra hard work